# Large file streaming confusion

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I want to handle large files in my application and microsoft documentation about [File Uploads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1#uploading-large-files-with-streaming) looks so bizarre. Why would I need `MultipartReader` whereas I would simply achieve what I want with the following:

```
@model SampleVM
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input asp-for="Prop1" />
    <input asp-for="Prop2" />
    <input type="button" value="Ok" onclick="post();"/>
</form>

@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    function post() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Prop1', $('#Prop1').val());
        formData.append('Prop2', $('#Prop2')[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index")',
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData
        });
    }
</script>
}
```

and in the controller I can simply get the stream with

```
var stream = vm.Prop2.OpenReadStream()
```

and do whatever I want. What does Microsoft documentation achieve with that spaghetti code that I don't with this simple sample?

Comment: "Why"    I doubt you'll get the answer you want.

Comment: If I get no answer, than I will follow the way I described. I just wonder if there is any sensible reason to use that way in the docs.

Comment: Could you link to their crazy method? They are probably preparing for scenarios you'll never face.

Comment: The link is in the hyperlink (the first sentence in the question). You can search for `public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()` to open the related method.

Comment: If the Prop2 parameter is declared as `IFormFile` then *I think* the whole file has already been buffered into memory, whereas `MultipartReader` has minimal buffering.

Comment: @MarkG Prop2 is `IFormFile` as you figured. However, it doesn't load it into memory. I already checked it using a very big file..

Comment: Based on [Uploading large files with streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads#uploading-large-files-with-streaming) it states in notes "Any single buffered file exceeding 64KB will be moved from RAM to a temp file on disk on the server".